# “well” modifying an another adverb

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis

Could you please give me a sentence where *well* (meaning *good*) modifies another adverb?

> Centrifugal force is a well-known principle of physics. (*well* modifying an adjective)
>
> She drives well. (*well* modifying a verb)

But can I create one where *well* will modify an another adverb?

Comment: Why do you think such a sentence exists?

Comment: I saw it here: Well is often used as an adverb. Adverbs can modify verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs. Good is most widely used as an adjective, meaning that it can modify nouns - http://blog.dictionary.com/well-vs-good/

Answer (score 1):

> He was well-deservedly knighted.

Here *well* modifies an adverb that modifies a participle.

Going by [Internet search results](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22well+deservedly%22), *well-deservedly* seems to be actually used.

Comment: Thank you. I would say well modifies an adjective here. To sum it up - it is impossible to create an example where well will modify an another adverb.

Comment: @user142410: And which adjective would that be?

Comment: I think it is "deservedly".

Comment: @user142410: I fail to see any argument for this. *Deservedly* here clearly modifies a verb *(knighted)* and not a noun. This is the central distinction between an [adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb) and an [adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective). Moreover it carries the characteristic adverb ending *ly* (and is not an exception like *ugly*). Can you state a definition of *adjective* and how it applies to *deservedly* here?

Comment: "Centrifugal force is a well-known principle of physics." (modifies the adjective known)"  - I was told this on a forum so I thought the example above is the same :)

Comment: @user142410: What’s your argument here? Apart from the hyphen, there is nothing these examples have in common.

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs *can* modify adverbs but that doesn't mean they must. It doesn't even mean that the majority can be used in that way. I cannot think of an example but it doesn't surprise me.

For example, 'slowly' is an adverb. Can you find an example where 'slowly' modifies another adverb?

Comment: "I very slowly walked to school" is an obvious answer where "very" Is an adverb modifying slowly.  "My slowly accelerated walking disturbed her" uses "walking" as a gerund and not a noun, so slowly still isn't modifying an adverb.

Comment: I didn't understand the point you just made. In the phrase 'I very slowly walked', the adverb 'slowly' is not modifying an adverb, it is modifying the verb 'walked'.  Therefore it is not an answer to my (rhetorical) question.

Comment: I was agreeing with you with some examples.  I wasn't trying to contradict you.